# Trouble converting strings of letters to integers

Tags: java, arrays

My program asks a question multiple times by an array but I need to get the answer from that String turned into the integer `1`. Know I know how to convert any old String into it's integer counterpart if the string is a bunch of number i.e `numbers = 12345` using `Integer.parseInt(numbers)`. What happens if I have a character in the string but I want it to take an integer value of 1? I've got it set out this like this so far

```
String[] elements = {"Vote A for Football", "Vote B for Basketball"};
String question
int football = 0; // not sure if these should be strings or integers
int basketball = 0;
int tally;

for (String element : elements)
{
  System.out.println(element);
}

question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your favourite sport?");
tally = Integer.parseInt(question);
```

The last line is the part that gets me because I want them to vote by either entering `A` or `B` but I also need the console to print how many times they have voted for that sport (it's an array exercise so the question will appear multiple times).

Comment: Where in the loop do you ask the question repeatedly? You only ask a question and get input once, so right now it's easy to get the number of answers -- it's always only 1.

Comment: So you want to loop until the end of the world asking "What is your favorite sport" incrementing `football` or `basketball` by 1 each time A or B is answered ? I think your `question` variable should instead be named `answer`. Then don't parse it to int, check if the answer is equals to `A` and if so, increment `football` by 1. Else if `B` increment basketball, else display an error message and reprompt.

Comment: What you have mentioned, @Jean-FrançoisSavard is exactly what I wish to achieve - I want to increment football or basketball by 1 each time A or B is answered. I'm having some trouble doing that, however. If I check that the answer is equal to A or B using an if statement, I don't see how I would increment football or basketball in the same statement.

Comment: @Thuivel : Why do you have to do it in the same statement ? Put a statement block in braces, and one statement to capture the integer equivalent and another to increment the survey count. 

Also, since you mention that the comment by Jean-Francois Savard clarifies your question well, please include that information as part of the question itself, so that prospective answerers will have more clarify about the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.  I'm not sure what you're asking, but it would be best to keep the storage of values as integers, and keep strings more of an interface to the user.  This way you can readily calculate values without any conversion.  Only when you present it to the user should you need to convert.

Having said that, if you are parsing a string (like "A" or "B"), you can store their response as a string, and then compare it against a list of known values using if and equals:

```
if ("A".equals(question)){
    football++;
} else if ("B".equals(question)) {
    basketball++;
} else {
    // do nothing, process error, ask question again.
}
```

Also remember to close your statement when initializing your variable:

```
String question;
```

or

```
String question = "";
```

But as @Jean-François Savard mentions, the variable should make sense as well, so this would be clearer:

```
String userResponse = "";
```

Comment: This snippet obviously confirm that `question` should be renamed to `answer`. +1.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing! My if statement was looking for integers in the answer and that's what was causing the problem. Thank you so much for helping me clear that up. Also thanks @Jean-FrançoisSavard for helping me to clarify what I was trying to do, it made solving the problem easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to use Enums

```
public enum Game {
A {
    @Override
    public String getGame() {
        return "Football";
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumber() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }
},
B {
    @Override
    public String getGame() {
        return "Basketball";
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumber() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }
};

public abstract String getGame();
public abstract int getNumber();
```

}